# How do I create angular material dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an array of angular material controls and their properties.

I have an array of the list of my database collection and it's fields.

Also I have a data table in a specific component of my angular project that it will be filled with collection array elements data.

here is some sample codes:

collection field interface:

```
export interface ICollectionFields {
  columnTitle: string;
  Type: string;
  control: IControls;
  columnWidth: number;
}
```

collection interface:

```
export interface ICollections {
  collectionName: string;
  collectionFields: ICollectionFields[];
  collectionFieldValidation: IControlValidation[];
  hasPaginator: boolean;
  stickyColumn: number;
  stickyHeader: boolean;
}
```

controls interface:

```
export interface IControls {
  controlName: controlsEnum;
  placeHolder?: string;  // input, SelectTrigger
  type?: 'color'|'date'|'datetime-local'|'email'|'month'|'number'|'password'|'search'|'tel'|'text'|'time'|'url'|'week'; // input
  enabled?: boolean; // input
  matAutosize?: boolean; // input
  matAutosizeMaxRows?: number; // input
  matAutosizeMinRows?: number; // input
  matTextareaAutosize?: boolean; // textarea
  .
  .
}
```

my validators interface (Not important by now):

```
export interface IControlValidation {
  validatorTitle: string;
  validation_rols: string;
}
```

arrays defined so:

```
public collections: ICollections[] = [
  {
    collectionName: 'Brands',
    collectionFields: [
      {
        columnTitle : 'brandTitle',
        Type : dtEnum.string,
        control: {
          controlName: controlsEnum.input,
          placeHolder: 'Enter brand title',
          autocomplete: false,
        },
        columnWidth: 200
      }
    ],
    collectionFieldValidation: [{name: 'test'}],
    hasPaginator: true,
    stickyColumn: 0,
    stickyHeader: true
  }
];
```

I intended to add an icon button for editing every row of mentioned data table. when user clicked on it, a dialog box will be appeared.

In this dialog box I want to have suitable control related to the data type of every field of the row and specified control in my material array.

Now, my problem is 2 things:

1- How do I add controls to dialog box html section?

2- How do I dynamically add properties to every control?

I did't design data table yet. but theoretically I want to know how this is possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @HDM91 Thanks. It seems my 1st problem solved.

Comment: once you have created your component dynamically you can use component ref to add property to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created your components you have to add them to your module in the entry components. (In case you don't have separate modules) should be the app.module.

```
entryComponents: [ HeroJobAdComponent, HeroProfileComponent ]
```

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

```
NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent, ErrorComponent],
  imports: [
   ....
  ],
  providers: [
   ....
  ],
  entryComponents: [ HeroJobAdComponent, HeroProfileComponent ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution:

[Create a dynamic form with configurable fields and validations using angular 2+](https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da)